# Send Request to server side

Tags: java, mysql

I'm developing a Java Desktop application with MySQL Database, I have searched the internet for days, i need to do the following:

- (**Client**) Desktop application for client will have the GUI.
- (**Server**) Tomcat Server With Servlet.
- (**Database**) MySQL Database server.

Client send request for query in servlet, then servlet response to the client with result which will be filled in database.

- No SQL Queries, Updates, Inserts, Delete ... etc will be exist on the client side, all will be in the servlets.
- Is this the best way to make 3tier application?
- Can I use Another idea or technology to achieve this?
- I don't want to go for web application.

I need client send request to middle server, which will connect to database & getting the result then send them back to the client without letting the client connect directly to the database.

Note: The client will be used by Multiple users in same LAN.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to go for a web application? Desktop application is more difficult to update. And at the end of the day, your desktop application will be still communicating with the server, via HTTP or another protocol.

Comment: With a Tomcat server your client-server protocol will be HTTP. You might find an RMI (JRMP) protocol more efficient and easier to program with for a desktop (Swing/JavaFX) client. JBoss/WildFly or GlassFish might fit your particular case better than Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

A web application which is hosted on a server typically uses HTTP as the communication protocol. So if you want to build your GUI using Java then you will be sending http request on user actions and receiving http response which would be translated to updates on the GUI. You should perhaps use a library such as [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to send/recieve http response. For creating/deploying a servlet web application you can find lots of tutorials. However these days people use MVC frameworks like Spring MVC ,Struts, JSF etc., as a web application framework which helps immensely in developing web applications.

As your requirement is that there should not be any SQL data access related code on your Client side, all the data access will need to be done on server side and your server side should send an accepted data format (xml/json) to your GUI in the http response which you will need to parse (there are many libraries to parse xml/json) and extract information from.
So your GUI will not be doing any resultset handling. It would be done by the server (inside web application) and the web application would send the xml/json response to your GUI request.

The architecture you are trying to develop in typical thin client architecture. You can imagine your Java GUI as a replacement for web browser.

Comment: That really good, but one of the issues that i have, servlet that query my database how it will retain me the ResultSet? How To read this result set and fill my JTable.?

Comment: that exactly what I'm looking for, Where can i find some examples to learn from them? I'm already have an application ready & want to change it using JSON, so i can make some tests. I will post the results so others can benefit from it.

Comment: For a start you can have a look at http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/. This requires maven as a build tool and will create a war file as an output which can be put into tomcat and accessed.

Comment: That rely great, What i will do it: 1. On My Thin Client i will take off the SQL Queries. 2. On server side i will install Tomcat as a web server. 3. I will create Servlet that query the data base & returning the Result in JSON Format. 4. My Thin Client will connect to the server using HTTP Request will get the JSON Then i will decode it in my Thin Client. 5. If i want to use insert,Update,Delete Queries i don't need to use JSON, i can just request the servlet that responsible about the action need Or i need to do it JSON also?

Comment: When you are talking http, you have request parameters in GET/POST requests which you can send to server which the server can interpret and take suitable action ( like run a query / update etc) and send some data or confirmation in json response with which you can paint the GUI

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40197/discussion-between-ameera-khaleel-and-shailendra)